# What happens to a protected question if my reputation falls below the privilege threshold?

Tags: support, privileges, protected-questions

I got 15001 reputation points and protected a question which has 4 deleted answers.

What happens to that protected question if lose 15 reputation? Will it still appear as "Protected by Avinash Raj"?

Answer (score 10):

Why would it be gone? If you had the privilege at the time, the protection would remain.

Consider what would happen if questions that former mods deleted/closed/protected would lose their status when the mod stepped down...

In short - the only thing that would go if you went under 15k, would be your ability to protect other posts (and unprotect currently protected posts).